# A "Bitcoin for dummies" guide?

Tags: adoption, introducing-bitcoin, bitcoin-literature

I would like to introduce a number of people that are not necessarily tech-savvy to Bitcoin and instruct them how to make their first payments. Is there some "Bitcoin for dummies" guide that I could be referencing that would be understandable to anyone capable of using a computer and the internet payments?

Comment: Here is one more blog, a small eBook: https://infopedia.io/revolution-of-money/ 

Money and Payment systems of tomorrow - Bitcoin rise with crypto industry story.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 3):

I have created a page on the Wiki called ["First time buyers guide"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/First-time_buyers_guide). It is only a rough version at the time of writing, but hopefully it will be revised into a go-to guide for anyone wanting to make a payment with Bitcoin with as little unnecessary information as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should merge your page with https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Newbie_Guide and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_Bitcoins_(the_noob_version)

Comment: It looks like your first link doesn't have content

Answer (score 0):

[Bitcoin magazine](http://bitcoinmagazine.net/category/bitcoin-newbies/) has a Bitcoin newbies section with introduction articles on various Bitcoin topics.

Comment: The link is dead (404).

Answer (score 0):

I run http://howdoyoubuybitcoins.com/ to help people BUY bitcoins. I know it's not quite what you asked, but before you can make your first payment, you have to get bitcoins. Please help us improve the guide!

PS: Thank you for pointing out the error with QuickBitcoins! If you look in our top nav, we cover quite a few locations, companies, and methods of payment.

Comment: some similarity to http://HowToBitcoin.info/

Comment: Hmm, could use a bit more cross-linking. When I go to "Buy bitcoins with cash", I get told to visit two other profiles without really being linked to them. Moreover, some pages appear to be outdated - the credit card one says that you can buy bitcoins with QuickBitcoins, but the QuickBitcoins page says it is down. Asides that, it looks promising.

Comment: Domain seems to have been reclaimed and is for sale. No content only a few vague links.

Answer (score 0):

I'm cautiously replying to this.

I did write a book in this space, called Bitcoin Step by Step.  You can pick it up on Kindle.  [http://www.amazon.com/Bitcoin-Step-by-ebook/dp/B00A1CUQQU/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A1CUQQU)

I am trying to very carefully choose where I mention this.  I don't want to break the rules of the site, but I do think this is relevant to this question.

Comment: Well, you can mention any links that are relevant, even the ones you own and profit from, as long as you explicitly state your affiliation with them.

Answer (score 0):

This post might clarify what it is about: [Cryptocurrency for Dummies: Bitcoin and Beyond](http://www.toptal.com/bitcoin/cryptocurrency-for-dummies-bitcoin-and-beyond/#remote-developer-job)

Comment: Yeap guys I deleted it myself as I never push on leaving my answers and tips posted if the community think that they will be fine without it :) The post I am pointing covers this question. This blog is maintained by Toptal where I and Demir (post author) work. We are (i mean developers) write for our blog when we have time between the projects. And our posts are really good. So I decided to spread that to those who is looking for such kind of information. But again - it is completely up you guys to decide whether to let my comment be here, or drop it. I don't mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Bitcoin for the Befuddled by Chris Wilmer and Conrad Barski.

This book assumes you have no technical knowledge.

Verbiage from book:

Unless you've been living under a rock for the last couple of years, you've probably heard of Bitcoin—the game-changing digital currency used by millions worldwide.

But Bitcoin isn't just another way to buy stuff. It's an anonymous, revolutionary, cryptographically secure currency that functions without the oversight of a central authority or government. If you want to get into the Bitcoin game but find yourself a little confused, Bitcoin for the Befuddled may be just what you're looking for. Learn what Bitcoin is; how it works; and how to acquire, store, and spend bitcoins safely and securely.

You'll also learn:

```
Bitcoin's underlying cryptographic principles, and how bitcoins are created
The history of Bitcoin and its potential impact on trade and commerce
All about the blockchain, the public ledger of Bitcoin transactions
How to choose a bitcoin wallet that's safe and easy to use
How to accept bitcoins as payment in your physical store or on your website
Advanced topics, including Bitcoin mining and Bitcoin programming
```

With its non-technical language and patient, step-by-step approach to this fascinating currency, Bitcoin for the Befuddled is your ticket to getting started with Bitcoin. Get out from under the rock and get in the Bitcoin game. Just make sure not to lose your shirt.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you already know and how tech-savy your crowd is. These two can be added to the list.

- Beginner: https://whatisbitcoin.help
- Pro (developers):
  https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/book.asciidoc