# General book recommendation

Tags: bitcoin-literature

***Disclaimer for moderators***: I am not sure if such a question is allowed in this website. Please feel free to remove it in case it isn't. This question is based on a similar [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

There are currently many books on Bitcoin and cryptocurrency/blockchain in general and surely many more will be written. Some are easier to find, some harder. Some are very good, others quite the opposite. Good reviews on websites such as Amazon are not always on par with the quality of the book, and not all books can be found in one place. I propose to provide answers to this question recommending books. The rules are as follows:

1. Each answer must propose one book only.
2. Each answer must propose a different book.
3. The proposal has to contain the book's author and title. A short description and subjective opinion why this book is worth reading is admissible.

The votes for each answer will determine the relative quality of each book. Please refrain from downvoting a book - simply don't upvote it.

The idea behind this question is not to argue which book is the best, but to consolidate the knowledge in one place.

Comment: Please check out the tag [tag:bitcoin-literature], especially the possible duplicates https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4911/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5297/5406

Answer (score 2):

**Mastering Bitcoin** by Andreas M. Antonopoulos - [bitcoinbook.info](https://bitcoinbook.info/)

> Mastering Bitcoin is a book for developers, although the first two chapters cover bitcoin at a level that is also approachable to non-programmers. Anyone with a basic understanding of technology can read the first two chapters to get a great understanding of bitcoin.

The first version was published in 2014, the second edition with updates was published in 2017. Although you can get a physical copy on amazon, the whole book is available on [github](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook). The second version can be read here: https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/book.asciidoc

I find the book a good introduction to bitcoin for developers because it gets a good first explanation of Keys, Addresses, Transactions, Scripting and so on, and it does that not on the typical management level but also goes into the technical details of it. Although the book is somewhat older, the author also tries to explain new features of Bitcoin such as Lightning and Segwit, which you can find in the second edition in the [Chapter 12](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/second_edition_print2/ch12.asciidoc) and [Appendix](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/second_edition_print2/appdx-segwit.asciidoc).

You may find better resources on newer topics like segwit, but I believe the book is still a good starting point for coders to get into bitcoin.

A good overview of the books content you can find here: https://bitcoinbook.info/whats-new/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more blog, a small eBook:
https://infopedia.io/revolution-of-money/

Title: **(r)Evolution of Money**

Description:
Money and Payment systems of tomorrow -
Bitcoin rise with crypto industry story

Content:

1. Monetary Chronicles
2. Bitcoin Explanation
3. Comparative Advantage
4. Global Effects
5. Looking Forward

Published: 2022-10-01
by Boris Djurdjevic

Disclaimer: I'm the author.