# Bitcoin Core Security

Tags: bitcoin-core, security, bitcoin-core-development, full-node, wallet-security

Is there any site or resource where I can learn how to do security transactions while trading on bitcoin testnet

Comment: The testnet is for testing. Its coins (testnet BTC, or tBTV) have 0 value. There is nothing anyone would want to trade it for.

Comment: I know but I'm working on testnet because I'm new to this stuff

Comment: What do you mean 'security transactions' ?

Comment: What do you mean by trading?

Comment: @darosior in my transactions sending money etc. How can I protect my transactions from the hackers like protecting a website you made from hackers

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I mean doing transactions for example "signrawtransactionwithkey" or "sendrawtransaction"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General book recommendation](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93420/general-book-recommendation)